# Can't use a custom theme in my vaadin project

Tags: css, intellij-idea, vaadin7

I want to do some minor styling in to my app and so I tried to create a custom theme. I'm using IntelliJ Idea as an IDE for this project.

I've set my theme in folder: web/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
I've also copied valo theme from jar to themes folder ( not sure if needed )

I've following css-code in mytheme/styles.css file:

```
@import "../valo/styles.css";

.blackColor {
background: black;
}
```

In my UI, I've tried to use setTheme("mytheme"); in init method and annotation before the class.

The result is, I can apply the .blackColor just fine to components but it completely forgets the valo theme. It's like my custom theme is the only css file that is in use. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If this is your first take on vaadin themes, you should take a look at the [book section on themes](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html) and the [valo - getting started](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Valo+theme+-+Getting+started) wiki page. You will see that it is not necessary to copy the theme from the jars, you just need to *inherit / extend* it.

Suppose you're going by the example in the book, you'll have a `mytheme.scss` with your styles:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  .blackColor {
    background: black;
  }
}
```

And the `styles.scss`

```
@import "mytheme.scss";


.mytheme {
  @include mytheme;
}
```

After this, simply annotate your UI with the theme's name:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {
...
}
```

As per the book, please be aware that

> If no styles.css exists in the folder, the Sass file is compiled
>   on-the-fly when the theme is requested by a browser.

**Note:** you can find some nice examples of customizing the valo variables [here](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/tree/master/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had to actually do a maven project for this to work. Maven project automatically creates these files and directories. Used this "tutorial" https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.idea.html Before this, I tried to do excactly as you suggested but for some reason it didn't work out.

Comment: @JohnnSzm you created `mytheme/styles.css` instead of `mytheme/styles.scss` so it did not compile anything.